Is there an obligation to check blood spots in non-chicken eggs
According to Halacha, is there any obligation to check for blood spots in eggs from birds other than chickens? Is there a different din that is applicable or not?

The Shulchan Aruch doesn't specify chicken eggs, or any other kind of eggs. It would seem that there is an equal obligation to check any kind of egg for blood spots. And the reason for checking for blood, namely that the egg might be fertilized, applies equally to all bird eggs.
However, there is one distinction: these days, most supermarket chicken eggs are laid by hens that were grown alone, with no rooster nearby. This means that no blood spots in eggs are the result of fertilization, and therefore the prohibition on eating the blood is not as strong (and if a blood spot is found after eggs are scrambled, for example, you'd be allowed to leave it). However, other birds that aren't commonly raised for eggs might not fall into this category, and therefore these leniencies wouldn't be permitted.

The opposite could also apply: eggs from species that almost never have blood spots (if such a thing exists) would not need to be checked at all

Anybody know what the blood-spot ratio is for quail eggs?

Where does the Shulchan Aruch you link to discuss an obligation to check for blood? I just see it discussing what to do if you found blood

Interesting question!
Want to be clear here: I’m not paskening anything, just stating the opinions and drawing logical sourced conclusions:
The Rema in Y.D. Siman 66:8 quoting the הגהות מיימוני וארוך, Kaf Hachaim here, Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. Siman 66:32, and Shu”t Vayvarech David 2:92 all say that nowadays one does not need to check eggs for blood, but everyone agrees that there is a minhag or chumrah of some sorts to check for blood. The reason one would not need to check for the blood in the times of the Rema or earlier is because as the Rema says we rely on a rov (majority) that most eggs don't have blood.
Nowadays we don't need to check it because of what it says here:

"“the vast majority of eggs which are found in supermarkets today are the product of hormonal and artificial stimulation and not a result of the natural reproductive process of chickens. Manipulating chickens in this way can generate a new egg every single day, making the process extremely profitable. These mass produced eggs, often referred to as "commercial eggs" or "battery eggs", will never develop into chickens. As such, the "blood spots" found in these eggs are not truly blood. The only eggs which are produced by natural fertilization today are clearly marked as "natural" or "organic" on the package and are significantly more expensive. When one finds blood in naturally fertilized eggs, the blood is not kosher and the egg must be discarded.  The reason for this is due to the concern that the blood might actually be the early stages of an embryo.”

Therefore, eggs that come from kosher birds like ducks, geese, turkey, etc would not have to be checked, 1) because most eggs don't have blood (the rov), since the Rema and other Achronim did not differentiate between chickens and other birds. 2) For the reason of most eggs being a product of "commercial eggs" or "battery eggs,” one would not need to check the package if the eggs are "commercial eggs" or "battery eggs,” and even if they are natural or organic eggs one can rely on the Rema that most eggs don't have blood (rov).
Hope this helps!
